# Nopcommerce Plugin Configure page issue

Tags: nopcommerce

Nopcommerce throws an error when I click the configure button of the plugin I created.

It is a payments plugin using Instamojo. Below is the error that I am getting :

Unable to resolve service for type 'ImageResizer.Configuration.Logging.ILogger' while attempting to activate 'Nop.Plugin.Payments.Instamojo.Controllers.PaymentInstamojoController'.'

I am new to nopcommerce and have no idea where this is coming from.

Comment: Are you using `ImageResizer.Configuration.Logging.ILogger` anywhere in `PaymentInstamojo Controller`? register it's dependency in `DependencyRegister.cs` file

Comment: thanks, I'll try that.